# How to copy rows into a new a one to many relationship

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to copy a set of data in a one to many relationship to create a new set of the same data in a new, but unrelated one to many relationship. Lets call them groups and items. Groups have a 1-* relation with items - one group has many items.

I've tried to create a CTE to do this, however I can't get the items inserted (in y) as the newly inserted groups don't have any items associated with them yet. I think I need to be able to access old. and new. like you would in a trigger, but I can't work out how to do this.

I think I could solve this by introducing a previous parent id into the templateitem table, or maybe a temp table with the data required to enable me to join on that, but I was wondering if it is possible to solve it this way?

SQL Fiddle Keeps Breaking on me, so I've put the code here as well:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS meta.templateitem;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS meta.templategroup;

CREATE TABLE meta.templategroup (
 templategroup_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 groupname text,
 roworder int
);

CREATE TABLE meta.templateitem (
 templateitem_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 itemname text,
 templategroup_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES meta.templategroup(templategroup_id)
);

INSERT INTO meta.templategroup (groupname, roworder) values ('Group1', 1), ('Group2', 2);
INSERT INTO meta.templateitem (itemname, templategroup_id) values ('Item1A',1), ('Item1B',1), ('Item2A',2);


WITH 
x AS (
    INSERT INTO meta.templategroup (groupname, roworder) 
        SELECT distinct groupname || '_v1' FROM meta.templategroup where templategroup_id in (1,2)
        RETURNING groupname, templategroup_id, roworder
    ),
y AS (
    Insert INTO meta.templateitem (itemname, templategroup_id)
        Select itemname, x.templategroup_id
        From meta.templateitem i 
        INNER JOIN x on x.templategroup_id = i.templategroup_id
        RETURNING *
    )
SELECT * FROM y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an auxiliary column `templategroup.old_id`:

```
ALTER TABLE meta.templategroup ADD old_id int;

WITH x AS (
    INSERT INTO meta.templategroup (groupname, roworder, old_id) 
        SELECT DISTINCT groupname || '_v1', roworder, templategroup_id
        FROM meta.templategroup 
        WHERE templategroup_id IN (1,2)
        RETURNING templategroup_id, old_id
    ),
y AS (
    INSERT INTO meta.templateitem (itemname, templategroup_id)
        SELECT itemname, x.templategroup_id
        FROM meta.templateitem i 
        INNER JOIN x ON x.old_id = i.templategroup_id
        RETURNING *
    )
SELECT * FROM y;

 templateitem_id | itemname | templategroup_id 
-----------------+----------+------------------
               4 | Item1A   |                3
               5 | Item1B   |                3
               6 | Item2A   |                4
(3 rows)
```

It's impossible to do that in a single plain sql query without an additional column. You have to store the old `ids` somewhere. As an alternative you can use plpgsql and anonymous code block:

Before:

```
select *
from meta.templategroup
join meta.templateitem using (templategroup_id);

 templategroup_id | groupname | roworder | templateitem_id | itemname 
------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------
                1 | Group1    |        1 |               1 | Item1A
                1 | Group1    |        1 |               2 | Item1B
                2 | Group2    |        2 |               3 | Item2A
(3 rows)
```

Insert:

```
do $$
declare
    grp record;
begin
    for grp in
        select distinct groupname || '_v1' groupname, roworder, templategroup_id
        from meta.templategroup 
        where templategroup_id in (1,2)
    loop
        with insert_group as (
            insert into meta.templategroup (groupname, roworder) 
            values (grp.groupname, grp.roworder)
            returning templategroup_id
        )
        insert into meta.templateitem (itemname, templategroup_id)
            select itemname || '_v1', g.templategroup_id
            from meta.templateitem i
            join insert_group g on grp.templategroup_id = i.templategroup_id;
    end loop;
end $$;
```

After:

```
select *
from meta.templategroup
join meta.templateitem using (templategroup_id);

 templategroup_id | groupname | roworder | templateitem_id | itemname  
------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------+-----------
                1 | Group1    |        1 |               1 | Item1A
                1 | Group1    |        1 |               2 | Item1B
                2 | Group2    |        2 |               3 | Item2A
                3 | Group1_v1 |        1 |               4 | Item1A_v1
                3 | Group1_v1 |        1 |               5 | Item1B_v1
                4 | Group2_v1 |        2 |               6 | Item2A_v1
(6 rows)
```

Comment: I was hoping to do this without introducing a new column as I don't have control over the DB itself. Is it possible without, as this suggestion means I need to add another column to the templategroup table.